# Ajax Response Return Old Image

Tags: php, ajax

I Am Using PHP + ajax

On Click I re-size Image On run time and save re-size image on disk and then display that Success Re-size Image In another div.

Image Resize  Occur Successfully and ajax return that new image.

But its show old resize image.

in success return i also first used

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'home/FlipImage/'+send+'/'+save_name,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
```

and also

```
$('#right_border').empty();
```

and after that i place my new image in this div but still getting old response

```js
$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo $url ?>home/FlipImage/'+send+'/'+save_name,
type: 'POST',
cache: false,
success: function(data){
$('#right_border').html('');
$('#left-border').html('');
$('#right_border').empty();
$('#left-border').empty();
var HorImg    = host+'test/uploads/canvas_uploads/FlippedImages/HerFlip_'+save_name+'';
var VerImg    = host+'test/uploads/canvas_uploads/FlippedImages/VerFlip_'+save_name+'';
$('#right_border').html('<img src="'+HorImg+'"  >');
$('#left-border').html('<img src="'+HorImg+'" >');         
}
})
```

Comment: can you show us your complete ajax call along with your success and failure methods.

Comment: @HissamKhan Please update that in the question and don't use comments for this!

Comment: @Hissam Khan you are actually posting the data but i do not see any data parameter in you `$.ajax` call also you are returning `data` from server on ajax call but not using it

Answer (score 1):

Try this to avoid cached images:

```
$('#right_border').html('<img src="'+HorImg+'?' + (new Date()).getMilliseconds() + '"  >');
$('#left-border').html('<img src="'+HorImg+'?' + (new Date()).getMilliseconds() + '" >');
```

It works in Chrome's Console:

[image]

Comment: Lemme check once and get back! Please wait @HissamKhan.

Comment: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal


('<img src="'+HorImg+'?' + (new Date()).getMilliseconds() + " >');

Comment: You left a `'` there! Try this: `('<img src="'+HorImg+'?' + (new Date()).getMilliseconds() + '" >');`

Comment: *psst: My mistake in answer, sorry!*

Comment: Still Getting Old Image :( After 2 3 response is show fresh image :(